# Unable to locate "Login" button in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code looks like this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[starts-with(@type,’submit’)]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button']")).click();
```

The error is:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/*[/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button']' is not a valid XPath expression.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyzyK.jpg)

Please let me know, how can I automate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would suggest you to go for Relative based Xpath than Absolute based.
 use this below:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
driver.findElementByXpath("//button[starts-with(@type,'submit')]")).click();
```

You have kept . before  '//' which is not required and if this doesn't work lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
```

[] is for conditions. Example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[contains(., 'bla')]"));
```

./ or .// is for finding children elements of an element. Example:

```
var RcdRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body//tr"));
var RcdTd = RcdRow.findElement(By.XPath(".//td[3]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra quote in your code after "button". Also .//* is used for relative path so you don't have to use it here since you are using absolute path to the button element.